# How to access event data?

Tags: python, bokeh

Click handlers in bokeh 1.0.3 used to have the signature `attr, old, new`. Now the are passed a single event object. How can I access its values?

```py
menu = [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]
dropdown = Dropdown(label='clickme', menu=menu)
def click_handler(event):
    print(event)
```

returns

> bokeh.events.MenuItemClick object at 0x7ff7de1cc208

EDIT: Where in the documentation is access to values of events described? I could not find anything on https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/events.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm coming in [late](https://xkcd.com/979), but I had the same issue as Leevi, and bigreddot's answer did not work for me (Bokeh 2.4.2, Python 3.10.2). Short answer is that a Bokeh Dropdown does not have a `value` attribute, so `on_change('value, handler)` will not work. The `MenuItemClick` object, has an `item` attribute, which is what you want.

```
    menu = [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]
    dropdown = Dropdown(label='clickme', menu=menu)

    def click_handler(event):
        print(event.item)
    dropdown.on_click(click_handler)
```

*Long answer:* I had the following code:

```
def choose_pipeline(event):
    """Change to the chosen pipeline"""
    print(event)
pipeline_dropdown = Dropdown(label='Available Pipelines', 
                             menu=[("Pipeline1", "pipeline1_value"),
                                   ("Pipeline2", "pipeline2_value")])
pipeline_dropdown.on_change('value', choose_pipeline)
```

and got this error:

```
File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\DHLLDV\Scripts\SystemTab.py", line 69, in system_panel
    pipeline_dropdown.on_change('value', choose_pipeline)
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\DHLLDV\venv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\model\model.py", line 434, in on_change
    descriptor = self.lookup(attr)
  File "C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\DHLLDV\venv\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\has_props.py", line 469, in lookup
    raise AttributeError(f"{cls.__name__}.{name} property descriptor does not exist")
AttributeError: Dropdown.value property descriptor does not exist
```

I wrote this:

```
    def choose_pipeline(event):
        """Change to the chosen pipeline"""
        print(event.__dict__)
    pipeline_dropdown = Dropdown(label='Available Pipelines', menu=[("Pipeline1", "pipeline1_value"),
                                                                  ("Pipeline2", "pipeline2_value")])
    pipeline_dropdown.on_click(choose_pipeline)
```

And saw the result when I picked Pipeline2:

```
{'item': 'pipeline2_value', '_model_id': '1365'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got this information, but it's not quite correct. `Dropdown` was refined as a type of `Button` recently, so the ability to respond to the same kind of click events that other buttons do was *added*. But nothing was replaced. Callbacks for property changes work for any Bokeh object property, including `Dropdown.value`, and this has not changed:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import Dropdown

menu = [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]
dropdown = Dropdown(label='clickme', menu=menu)

def cb(attr, old, new):
    print(attr, old, new)
dropdown.on_change('value', cb)

curdoc().add_root(dropdown)
```